# Linking between dask.distributed and LSF cluster

Tags: parallel-processing, lsf, dask-distributed

I'm using IBM's LSF platform to run my code in parallel. At the moment, this entails "manually" breaking the code into a job array; instead of:

```
for i in range(100):
    x[i] = f(i)
```

I distribute `f` over 100 workers, and then "manually" collect all their 100 different results to `x`.

I'm trying to understand if `dask.distributed` can be used as a "bridge" between my simulation kernel (an IPython kernel in this case) and the LSF scheduler in a way that distributes and gathers the calculations in an automated fashion.

I couldn't find any documentation on this... any help would be much appreciated!